# sequential model testing in keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using sequential model because in my actual data, order is important. So I'm testing with a very simple problem.

Using this data structure, since my actual project uses this.

The keras model is supposed to find the sum of the elements for each 4-element array and return an array of the results.

Am new to machine learning.

Keep getting the same low accuracy in my results.

1. would it make a difference if I switch to pytorch ?
2. Are my layers wrong ?

code:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras import activations
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam
    
    
x_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(200,50, 4))
y_train = []
for i in x_train:
    b = []
    for j in i:
        b.append(sum(j))
    y_train.append(b)

y_train = np.asarray(y_train)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=(50,4), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=50, epochs=150)

x_test = np.random.randint(2, size=(2,50, 4))
y_test = model.predict(x_test)
```

UPDATED sample of results with accuracy of 0.3:

```
[1.8860947] [1 1 0 0]
[1.8860947] [1 1 0 0]
[2.8001838] [1 0 1 1]
[0.9009073] [0 0 1 0]
[1.8860947] [1 1 0 0]
[0.9719887] [0 1 0 0]
[1.0507569] [1 0 0 0]
[1.8607054] [0 0 1 1]
[2.8148863] [0 1 1 1]
[3.6628482] [1 1 1 1]
[0.9719887] [0 1 0 0]
[3.6628482] [1 1 1 1]
[1.8607054] [0 0 1 1]
[0.9009073] [0 0 1 0]
[1.9050169] [0 1 1 0]
```

Comment: why did you use Dense(1, activation = 'softmax')?  Also why loss is categorical_crossentropy?

Comment: oh, I got that from an example. i'm a noob

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example/sample of your actual data as well as the details of the output.

Comment: I would like to know why this model isn't working as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you are trying to get linear results, however you have a non-linear activation at the output layer. Softmax outputs predictions, you should use it when you have more than 2 classes in your dataset, i.e when making classification models. And its' elements sum is always 1. Changing following line can help:

```
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Comment: ah ty! makes more sense. I am getting an accuracy of 0.3 now...better than 0.1

Comment: Having 0.3 accuracy can be related to your data. Check x_train and y_train then confirm if everything is OK etc.

Comment: OK, updated question with my results. looks good !?

Comment: My mistake, you should not use 'accuracy' metric when doing regression with keras, because it is for classification problems. From your test results you can see model is learning actually. For further metrics you search up for keras metrics. I edited my answer.